# Storing Allowed Websites Per User in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a User table in my Postgres database. In my application, the User can have various allowed websites. My question is: which is more disk space efficent, having a many-to-many relationship between a user and a url or storing the array in JSON in a column in the User table. Essintially, how much space does postgres use to store table headers.

Thanks.

Comment: A totally valid theoretical question, the way postgresql stores it's values (looking at the source, or a raw datafile is an option), but if you're seriously concerned about disk-space for this relation (instead of performace/otherwise), and the amount of users-relations is under several hundred million, you have more pressing problems.

Comment: I just read a book on scaling web applications. Since I'm working on a new web application, I thought I might as well design it with scalability in mind.

Comment: @Max: Do not design with scalability in mind if it means *premature optimization*.  If you think something is slow, benchmark it.  If it really is slow, then and only then should you optimize it, and then only if it's the slowest part that will gain the most benefit from optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is more disk space efficent, having a many-to-many relationship between a user and a url or storing the array in JSON in a column in the User table.

Updating a many-to-many relationship means an UPDATE (and/or DELETE?) statement.

Updating a JSON array stored in a database tables means:

1. SELECTing the data to get it out of the database, to the application
2. Manipulating the data in the application
3. UPDATE statement to write the updated JSON array back to the table

Which is simpler/more efficient to you?

Comment: Postgres has a native array type - it doesn't involve that much application manipulation. (Not that I'm saying the array method is better, I agree with a many-to-many.)

Comment: @rfusca: I was trying to find how many bytes Postgre allocates for VARCHAR - do you have a link?

Comment: There a section that talks a bit about it.  Its a little hard to calculate because postgres will automatically compress long strings.
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html